# JNI crash after Square Reader SDK update

Tags: android, java-native-interface, square-reader

For a long time I've been running the **Square Reader SDK (1.5.5)** on a device with **Android 7**. Then had to update the SDK to **1.7.4** and changed the device with **Android 9**.

The following crash occurs after updating the SDK

`JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI FindClass called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lcom/squareup/cardreader/CardInfo;.<init>(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/squareup/cardreader/EmvApplication;II)V"`

An interesting thing is that the app actually loads, but 3-4 seconds after that crashes with the error from above.

Info about the app:

- Obfuscation is disabled
- compiledSdkVersion = 32
- minSdkVersion = 24
- targetSdkVersion = 31

I went through the Square documentation for integrating their Reader SDK without any success.

Comment: The error is exactly what it is. The native code is trying to call a method that does not exist. Verify that you upgraded both the java part and the native part of the sdk and if you did, contact square support instead of stackoverflow.